# Unathorized Access to Google Drive

Tags: authentication, passwords, malware, privacy

My Google Account was hacked granting unauthorized access to YouTube and Google Drive. The third party immediately started posting inappropriate content on YT which prompted an email from Google after a couple of hours after which I changed my security settings and password. Aside from the password, my Google Account had been secured with phone authentication for unrecognized devices prior to the breach.  My question is were they able to access my Google Drive? If yes, I have not seen any activity on the activity log for each folder (sharing, moving or something else) other than me. Does that suggest they have not taken over the files or what?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is were they able to access my Google Drive?

Yes.

> Does that suggest they have not taken over the files or what?

We can't rule out that they may have accessed (but not written to) your files or even synced said files to a local computer wholesale.

Comment: How likely is the second part? If the files were set to private.

Comment: @nix9247 They broke into your Google account. Anything you had access to on that account, they had access to as well. How likely it is depends on their MO. It is highly likely they looked in there for stuff they can use for their own gain. If your Google Drive repository is more than a couple of files, a straight up sync would be the most sensible option, assuming they have your password.

Comment: I have checked all the activity ccon GoogleDrive, and did not record any suspicious views, changes, moves, or downloads (not even on my end if I was spoofed). Is that a good sign or just wishful thinking? :(